# How to sort "instock:0" items to end of query

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a cursor of products in my meteor application and each product knows it's current inventory via the "instock" property. The products are sorted alphabetically in the store but I would like all products where `instock <= 0` or `instock === 0` to be sorted to the bottom of the search results.

I have tried the following sort options in meteor.

`options = {sort: [['instock', 'desc], [name]] }`

This puts all instock === 0 properties to the end of the cursor but does not preserve the alphabetical sorting of the other products.

Is there a way in meteor and MongoDB to just put the fields with a certain value to the end of results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you will need to create two separate cursors and display one after the other. That is because selectors in Mongo are separate from options. The selector is used to filter data, the options are used to sort data among other things.

sample template helpers:

```
stockedItems: function(){
 return products.find({},{instock:{$gt:0}},{sort:{name:-1}})
}
outOfStockItems: functions(){
 return products.find({},{instock:{$lte:0}},{sort:{name:-1}})
}
```

sample template:

```
<ul>
{{#each stockedItems}}
<li>{{Title}}</li>
{{/each}}
{{#each outOfStockItems}}
<li>{{Title}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```